# python nested dict to csv with many columns

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, nested

I gathered info about the universities on siggragh, using nested dict, like this

```
universityDict['utah'][2008] = 11
universityDict['utah'][2009] = 0
```

means utah is nominated 11 times in 2008 and 0 times in 2009.(assumption)
as I got many columns - 2008 2009 2010 .... and so on.
how can I output them into a csv file in a neat way?

```
    for key,value in universityDict.items():
    writer.writerow({'university': key, '2008':value[2008] })#not this way
```

I want the the csv like:

```
university,2006,2007

utah,4,8

mit,0,4
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the indentation issue is not a real issue, you are doing it wrongly in your code.

Inside your first loop, you again need to iterate through the nested dictionary and put them into the csv.

Example -

```
for key,value in universityDict.items():
    d = {'university': key}
    d.update(value)

    writer.writerow(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in two steps as shown:

```
import csv

universityDict = {'arizon': {2006:  4, 2007:  3},
                  'ohio':   {2008:  3, 2009: 10, 2010: 5},
                  'utah':   {2008: 11, 2009:  0}}

# first determine what years are present to use to define the csv fieldnames
years = set((year for nominations in universityDict.values()
                    for year in nominations))
fieldnames =['university'] + sorted(years)

# next write the csv file and convert nested nominations to data for row
with open('university_nominations.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for university,nominations in universityDict.items():
        row = {'university': university}
        row.update(nominations)
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Contents of csv file created:

```
university,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010
ohio,,,3,10,5
utah,,,11,0,
arizon,4,3,,,
```